# When, and why did people use 1-starting P2PKH address to represent bare-pubkey P2PK outputs?

Tags: address, genesis-block

I notice that some web blockchain explorer, like https://blockstream.info, doesn't show the famous "Satoshi's bitcoin genesis address" (1A1zP1eP5QGefi2DMPTfTL5SLmv7DivfNa) for me in the genesis block: https://blockstream.info/block/000000000019d6689c085ae165831e934ff763ae46a2a6c172b3f1b60a8ce26f
[image: Genesis block showed by blockstream.info]

The same happens to the famous "first used (spent) bitcoin address ever" (12cbQLTFMXRnSzktFkuoG3eHoMeFtpTu3S) as well:
https://blockstream.info/block/000000008d9dc510f23c2657fc4f67bea30078cc05a90eb89e84cc475c080805
[image: Block #9 showed by blockstream.info]

AFAIK, these addresses have been mentioned in various places, like [this analysis on genesis block](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=172009.0) - despite technically such addresses "didn't exist at all" because P2PK outputs are different than P2PKH outputs.